# How to bind reference lifetime to a function local scope

Tags: rust

I want to write a function A which takes as parameter a function B which takes as parameter a type which is parameterized by a reference type which lifetime is at least the lifetime of the local variables in A’s body.

Consider the following example:

```rust
struct Foo {}

fn consume(mut v: Vec<&Foo>) {
    while let Some(..) = v.pop() {
        // Do stuff
        continue;
    }
}

fn setup_and<F>(f: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut Vec<&Foo>) + Send,
{
    let mut v: Vec<&Foo> = vec![];
    let other_foo = Foo {};

    f(&mut v);
    v.push(&other_foo);
    consume(v);
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {};
    setup_and(|v| {
        v.push(&foo);
    });
}
```

rustc cannot infer lifetimes on its own. It complains:

```
error[E0597]: `foo` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:25:17
   |
24 |     setup_and(|v| {
   |               --- value captured here
25 |         v.push(&foo);
   |         --------^^^-
   |         |       |
   |         |       borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `foo` is borrowed for `'static`
26 |     });
27 | }
   | - `foo` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I tried to specify a lifetime for the reference taken by `setup_and` like so:

```rust
fn setup_and<'a, F>(f: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut Vec<&'a Foo>) + Send,
{
    let mut v: Vec<&'a Foo> = vec![];
```

Now rustc complains about the `setup_and` local reference `other_foo` not living long enough. I assume it is because it wants a larger lifetime than the scope of `setup_and`.

How would I bind lifetimes correctly in that case ? I would like to express that the references must be valid until the end of the `consume` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a serious, serious issue with conflicting lifetimes in your implementation, and there is no simple fix without at least a partial redesign of the outside signatures of your `struct` and methods. They all stem from the `setup_and` method, and are highlighted by the compiler when you explicitly described the lifetime bounds.

The body of your method is copied below, with annotations for you to understand the issue:

```
let mut v: Vec<&Foo> = vec![];
let other_foo = Foo {}; // other_foo is created here

f(&mut v);
v.push(&other_foo); // other_foo requires lifetime 'a to be added to this
consume(v); // consume does not restrict the lifetime requirement 'a
// other_foo is dropped here, at lifetime less than 'a
```

The easiest solution to this problem is to store an `Arc<Foo>`, like so ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b4563d510765d3d856b34642b704ecc)):

```
fn setup_and<F>(f: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut Vec<Arc<Foo>>) + Send,
{
    let mut v: Vec<Arc<Foo>> = vec![];
    let other_foo = Foo {};

    f(&mut v);
    v.push(Arc::new(other_foo));
    consume(&mut v);
}
```

`Arc` is an Atomic Reference-Counting pointer. It is a clonable structure that works as a dynamic pointer to an object on the heap; for all intents and purposes, it works as a read-only reference, without the requirement for a lifetime. When all copies of an `Arc` are dropped, the item inside it is also dropped.

This solves two problems:

1. Your `other_foo` is now **moved** into the `Arc`, and no longer causes its lifetime issue
2. You can now access your objects just like you would a reference (`Arc` implements `Deref`)

The choice of `Arc` was made because your `FnOnce` requires `Send`, which `Rc` (the single-threaded variant of `Arc`) cannot provide.

Comment: Indeed I could use an Arc here to make that code work.

But I feel like there should be a way for a correct lifetime to parameterize my vector. Because the enclosed reference to `foo` will always outlive `&other_foo`, there should be one lifetime that is valid for both. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Theof You're missing the fact that `other_foo` is also getting pushed into your `Vec<>` as a reference and therefore has to live as long as what provided the lifetime requirement in the first place. It isn't about whether `foo` outlives `other_foo`, it is about the fact that `other_foo` needs to outlive the logical scope it is defined in, and since it is dropped (and destroyed) prior to that, it physically cannot.

Comment: I understand how the lifetime requirement I wrote makes rustc unhappy, but I feel like Rust should enable me to express the specific lifetime I am interested in. Seems, like there is no way to do that (yet ?), so I mark this as an answer thanks to the explanation.

Comment: @Theof Are you coming from a dynamic/garbage collected language? If so, I understand your problem. I've been in those shoes myself, and it just takes a bit of mental re-wiring in thinking about lifetimes. When you associate a lifetime to a reference as part of a collection, this lifetime will be the *largest* required lifetime; it won't be a different lifetime per object.